# Can you include a javascript script and also pass it a non-global variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm just wondering if it could be possible to include a script with jquery's `getScript()`, (or some other way) which contains a single self executing anonymous  function

```
(function(){

})(x)
```

and from an other function include that script, but also send a variable from it's local scope?
That way I could extend and use that variable without ever declaring it in the global scope.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery? /s

Comment: Do you mean to extend the global $?

Comment: No, it’s a running gag where essentially the answer to life is jQuery (hence /s, shorthand for sarcasm/joke)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I Tried to implement the below function and I was able to call it as a anonymous function without being declared global variable.  Sorry , if I wrongly understood your query

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button1").click(function(){
  getScriptHelper("script1")
 });

 $("button2").click(function(){
  getScriptHelper("script2")
 });

 var getScriptHelper= function(x)
 {
  var scriptpath = "demo_ajax_"+x+".js";
  $.getScript(scriptpath);
 }
});
```

Comment: I meant something like this: 

$.getScript(scriptpath, variable);

Then in the script which is being included I can access the variable that is being passed as the second arg.